# Python - Data type handling for data fetched by connecting to the MSSQL DB

Tags: python, sql-server, datetime

Using the below Python Code connected to the mssql db and tried fetching the data from the DB.

```
import pymssql
conn=pymssql.connect(host='localhost',user='sa',password='Password',database='HB')
mycursor=conn.cursor()
mycursor.execute("Select * from HB.dbo.TRANS")
results=mycursor.fetchall()
with open('Output.csv','w') as f:   
    for row in results:
        print str(row)
        s = ("%s\n" % str(row))
        f.write(s)
f.close()
```

Getting the output as :

```
(101, datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 1, 0, 0), 129.0, 0.0, 0.0, datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 22, 5, 50, 42, 83))
```

Expected Output:

```
(101, 2016:02:01 00:00:00.000, 129, 0, 0,2016:06:22 00:00:00.000, 5, 50, 42, 83)
```

How do i handle the datatype coming in the data fetched? (i.e Don't want the datatype (datetime.datetime) to appear in the data)

Comment: What do you mean by "handle"?

Comment: Handle as in, don't want the datatype to appear in the actual data fetched.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change `datetime.datetime()` object you can use **.strftime() method**

Example usage:

```
import datetime
some_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()
print(some_datetime) # will output: datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 24, 14, 57, 54, 190307)
print(some_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")) # will output: 2016-06-24 14:58:53
```

You may consider learning more about datetime python module **[here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html)**